# Determine what is causing the error "This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable" error

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, transactions, runtime-error

We run a proprietary web based Finance system created in ASP.NET that is throwing the following error on a regular basis:-

```
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException

Message: This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.

StackTrace:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.ZombieCheck()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.Rollback()
   at Agresso.Driver.Database.ManagedConnection.RollbackTransaction()
   at Agresso.Driver.Database.ManagedConnection.Close()
   at Agresso.Driver.Database.ManagedConnection.Dispose(Boolean isDisposing)
   at Agresso.Driver.Database.ManagedDatabase.Dispose(Boolean isDisposing)
   at Agresso.Driver.Database.DatabaseBase.Finalize()
```

The issue has been logged with the suppliers but they believe the error is due bespoke work that we have created ourselves.

What would you recommend as a way of determining what is causing the system to get into this state? We do not have access to debug the application but can run profiler on the database. However so far this has not shed any possible clues to what is causing the problem.

We are currently just restarting the app pool, which resolves the problem for a period of time before it occurs again.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pure speculation, but:

- if DatabaseBase.Finalize() is a .NET finalizer, it shouldn't be attempting to dispose managed resources - so this may well be a bug in the `DatabaseBase` class finalizer.
- However a finalizer for an `IDisposable` class is normally only called if the caller has failed to `Dispose` an instance of the class (the Dispose method usually calls GC.SuppressFinalize to prevent the finalizer from running).

I would start by looking at your own code that accesses the database, and make sure you call Dispose for all `IDisposable` types, typically by wrapping in a `using` block.  FxCop / Visual Studio Code Analysis can help you identify places in your code where you're failing to do this.

This may well clear up the problem.  If not, I suggest you try to create a minimal repro for the problem and contact the supplier again.